# gcc errors "conflicting types for" and "previous declaration of" during compiling

Tags: c

I am getting these errors despite declaring the "getline" and "copy" function prototypes before main(). This program comes straight from the code in *The C Programming Language* so I'm unsure what the issue is and how to fix it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int getline(char line[], int maxline);
void copy(char to[], char from[]);

int main()
{

}

int getline(char s[], int lim)
{
    int c, i;

    for (i=0; i<lim-1 && (c=getchar())!=EOF && c!='\n'; ++i)
        s[i] = c;
    if (c == '\n') {
        s[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }
    s[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}

void copy(char to[], char from[])
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while ((to[i] = from[i]) != '\0')
        ++i;
}
```

The exact errors produced by the compiler are:

```
string_reverser.c:4:5: error: conflicting types for 'getline'
 int getline(char line[], int maxline);
     ^~~~~~~

In file included from string_reverser.c:1:0:
c:\mingw\include\stdio.h:650:1: note: previous declaration of 'getline' was here
 getline (char ** __restrict__, size_t * __restrict__, FILE * __restrict__);
 ^~~~~~~

string_reverser.c:27:5: error: conflicting types for 'getline'
 int getline(char s[], int lim)
     ^~~~~~~

In file included from string_reverser.c:1:0:
c:\mingw\include\stdio.h:650:1: note: previous declaration of 'getline' was here
 getline (char ** __restrict__, size_t * __restrict__, FILE * __restrict__);
 ^~~~~~~
```

Comment: `getline` is a function in `stdio.h`. You're re-defining it in your code, which includes `stdio.h`.

Comment: Also `getline` probably didn't exist at the time the book was written.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: The probability of [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) not existing as a POSIX function when K&R 2nd Edn was written is 100%.  It wasn't in POSIX 2004; it arrived in POSIX 2008.  The book was about 20 years old by then.

Comment: morality: always give your functions funny names just in case they collide with standard functions in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The POSIX function [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) is now a standard library function which is (already) declared in `<stdio.h>` (but wasn't standard when K&R was written).
Hence, you cannot re-declare the function a little differently in C language.
A workaround is to rename your getline function to something else, e.g. getline_new
The updated code is as below with this workaround, or you may want to switch to C++ that gives flexibility to have many functions with same name, but different arguments, including argument type (polymorphism concept)

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int getline_new(char line[], int maxline);
    void copy(char to[], char from[]);

    int main()
    {

    }

    int getline_new(char s[], int lim)
    {
       int c, i;

       for (i=0; i<lim-1 && (c=getchar())!=EOF && c!='\n'; ++i)
        s[i] = c;
       if (c == '\n') {
        s[i] = c;
        ++i;
     }
     s[i] = '\0';
     return i;
    }

   void copy(char to[], char from[])
   {
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while ((to[i] = from[i]) != '\0')
        ++i;
   }
```